# How iOS6 displays the same tableView group style as iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6, tableview

**Cell in iOS6 has rounded corners, while in iOS7 is a rectangle.**

I have been working for more than a year, but the problem has been bothering me, if you can help me, I would be very grateful！

Comment: Could you post the relevant code, please?

Comment: `UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the new style, this is how it looks in iOS7+. If you wish to change this, you need to create custom cells that have UIViews inside them that you can modify.

You will need to add spacing on the left / right and will need to manually round the corners of the first / last cells.

However, as I mentioned, this is the new style. You should try find a way to make the new style work in your app rather than forcing it to look like the old iOS

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't say it clearly.I want to DIY zhe new style  not zhe old style

Comment: @Jaycee ok if you want to do it the other way its still a similar issue. Your trying to make it into a style that wasn't designed for it.  You need cells that go from left to right with the new group headers. You could easily achieve that by not having it grouped on iOS 6 and creating a cell that looks like the header and a cell that looks like the iOS 7 cell. But this is a lot of effort as it will need to be grouped in iOS 7 and not grouped in iOS 6. You should just leave it the way it is. Or drop support for iOS 6